# UIButton is resized without visible cause?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I have ViewController(1) which hierarchy is like this

```
ViewController
- UIView
-- UITableView (height 80% of it's superview)
-- UIButton ( height 20% of it's superview, 80% offset y)
```

After pressing the UIButton new ViewController is pushed. Till now everything is okay, but in the moment of the animation I see that UIButton is resized to fit in the entire view. After going back now i have my button on the entire view.

What can cause this problem to appear?

1.

```
UIPopOverController
- UINavigationController
-- UIViewController
```

EDIT 1:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    // ... 
    _storeButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    _storeButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
    _storeButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithHexString:(_productData.count > 0) ? @"0x8BC53F" : @"0xA4A4A4" ];
    [_storeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(storeButtonTouched:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    // ...
}

#pragma mark - Store request.
- (void)storeButtonTouched:(id)sender
{
    DLog(@"_storeButton: %@", _storeButton);

    if ( _productData != nil && _productData.count > 0) {
        _productData = [NSArray arrayWithArray:_iapManager.productData];

        TTIAPTableViewController *iapVC = [[TTIAPTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
        iapVC.entries = _productData;
        iapVC.contentSizeForViewInPopover = self.view.frame.size;

        [self.navigationController pushViewController:iapVC animated:YES];
        [iapVC release];

    } else {
        DLog(@"No products available.");
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you using autolayout?

Comment: Are you using the new Autolayout feature? 

If you are, go to your nib or stroyboard file, go to the 'File Inspector' section on the 'Utilities' panel (right). Untick the 'Use Autolayout' box.

Comment: I didn't use Autolayout nor Autoresizing Mask

Comment: what is value of `frame` in viewDidAppear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved through using [Containing ViewControllers](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/04/containing-viewcontrollers/).